# Hot to execute "spark-submit" against remote spark master?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I've got a remote spark cluster. I can log in a remote spark cluster host with `ssh` and run `spark-submit` with an example like that:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit /usr/lib/spark2/examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

Now I've installed `spark` on my laptop but I don't run it. 
I want to run `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit` on my laptop *against* the remote spark cluster host. How can I do it ?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Comment: Thanks. How can I figure out the right `--master` (given my access to the remote cluster) ?

Comment: I think you missed some important details here. Based on your previous question you are using YARN. In that case configuration depends on your Hadoop configuration and master is just `yarn`.

Comment: Thanks again. I do use `yarn` but if I want to connect to a _remote_ `yarn` I need to specify the `yarn` host, port, etc., don't I ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can provide the remote master url in this command, e.g.

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://url_to_master:7077 /usr/lib/spark2/examples/src/main/python/pi.py`